# Want to create alert on NEURAL NETWORK when the HMA changes color

Tags: pine-script

this is the code for the HMA portion of the script. I would love to add the function of having alerts trigger when the HMA changes color

```
//HMA///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
len6 = 100
src6 = close
hma = wma(2*wma(src6, len6/2)-wma(src6, len6), floor(sqrt(len6)))
hmacolor = close > hma ? #00bcd4 : #e91e63
plot(hma, title="HMA Line", color=color.new(hmacolor, 25), linewidth=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hma changes color based on `close > hma` condition. So, store its value in a variable and check if that variable's state has changed.

The following code will do:

```
//@version=4
study("My script")

len6 = 100
src6 = close
hma = wma(2*wma(src6, len6/2)-wma(src6, len6), floor(sqrt(len6)))
bull = close > hma
bear = not bull
hmacolor = close > hma ? #00bcd4 : #e91e63
plot(hma, title="HMA Line", color=color.new(hmacolor, 25), linewidth=5)
alertcondition(not bull[1] and bull, "Buy", "Buy")
alertcondition(not bear[1] and bear, "Sell", "Sell")
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU for your genius haha. I applied it successfully, however dont see a new option when creating an alert--going to see if this had an effect on the original alerts though

Comment: Make sure that your script is selected as a "condition" when you are creating an alert.

Comment: where would i put "condition"? Sorry new to Pine

Comment: Please see my edit. Added a screenshot.

Comment: ahhhh PERFECT okay thank you that cleared it up. Thank you so much again!